# NSPredicate filter

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have never used NSPredicate before so please bear with me. I have an array which have a boolean key as "isChecked". I want to filter the array which have the boolean set as "YES", any idea how can I do it, plus if there is any reference to such query methods that would be nice to have it handy.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using this in conjunction with Core Data, or do you just have an `NSArray` instance for which you want a subset matching your criteria?

Comment: @craig I have an instance of NSArray for which I want a subset matching my criteria. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
//NSArray * myArray is your array 
//containing your objects that each have an isChecked property


NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"isChecked == YES"];
NSArray *filteredArray = [myArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

// filteredArray is the new array that only contains your checked items
```

Cheers

Comment: Upvoted because great minds think alike. Same variable names and everything. :)

Comment: I had tried that and it didn't worked but when I tried NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"isChecked == 'YES'"]; it did, wonder what's the difference?

Comment: That's odd.  I'm actually using this exact predicate, and it works in my app.

Answer (score 3):

First you create an `NSPredicate` instance. In this case, we'll use `-initWithFormat:`.

`NSPredicate *predicate = [[NSPredicate alloc] initWithFormat:@"isChecked == YES"];`

Then we'll use the `-filteredArrayUsingPredicate:` method on `NSArray` to get an NSArray of all the objects which match the predicate.

`NSArray *filteredArray = [originalArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];`

Comment: You're leaking you're predicate here.  If you use the class method [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:] you don't have to worry about memory management of the predicate.

Comment: It's 2011. I'm assuming that most people are either using ARC or know basic memory management by now. Keep moving forward.

Comment: LOL I'm managing old apps right now and haven't even started using ARC yet.  I'll catch up soon I hope.